# How to fix error with Query dynamodb request?

Tags: go, post, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In DynamoDB I Have a table that contains:

```
- email (primary key)
- password (attribute)
- rname (attribute)
```

I'm using V1 of the AWS Go SDK, to implement to perform a query using just the primary key to my database:

My struct to unMarshal to is:

```
type Item struct {
    Email    string `json:"email"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
    Rname    string `json:"rname"`
}
```

and the code:

```
result, err := client.Query(&dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName: aws.String("accountsTable"),
        KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
            "email": {
                ComparisonOperator: aws.String("EQ"),
                AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    {
                        S: aws.String(email),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    item := []Item{}

    err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(result.Items, &item)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
```

However, I get the issue that the key is invalid. I check the key in the database and it matches the one i print out to the console too.

Not sure how to get round this issue as example's i've seen seem to work for their's and look the same.

Any help in fixing this issue would be appreciated thanks :)

[image: Table Details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the values of password and rname to `omitempty` so that it's not set to empty values as they are not keys they should not be included on a Query as it throws an invalid key exception:

```
type Item struct {
    Email    string `json:"email" dynamodbav:"email,omitempty"`
    Password string `json:"password" dynamodbav:"password,omitempty"`
    Rname    string `json:"rname" dynamodbav:"rname,omitempty"`
}
```

### Update

I believe the issue is due to the fact you try to marshall the entire response in a single command, however, iterating works for me. (I do not use Go).

```
package main
import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"

    "fmt"
)


func main() {

    // Create Session
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))

    // Create DynamoDB Client with Logging
    client := dynamodb.New(sess, aws.NewConfig())


    type Item struct {
        Email    string `dynamodbav: "email"`
        Password string `dynamodbav: "password,omitempty"`
        Rname    string `dynamodbav: "rname,omitempty"`
    }

    result, err := client.Query(&dynamodb.QueryInput{
        TableName: aws.String("accountsTable"),
        KeyConditions: map[string]*dynamodb.Condition{
            "email": {
                ComparisonOperator: aws.String("EQ"),
                AttributeValueList: []*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                    {
                        S: aws.String("lhnng@amazon.com"),
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Query API call failed:")
        fmt.Println((err.Error()))
    }



    for _, i := range result.Items {
        
        item := Item{}
        err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(i, &item)
    
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Got error unmarshalling: %s", err)
        }
    
        fmt.Println("Email: ", item.Email)
        fmt.Println()
        
    }
}
```

Moreover, as you use a single key of `email`, it means there is at most 1 item with the same email address, meaning you should use `GetItem` rather than `Query`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
)

func main() {

    // Item to Get
    type Item struct {
        Email    string `dynamodbav: "email"`
        Password string `dynamodbav: "password,omitempty"`
        Rname    string `dynamodbav: "rname,omitempty"`
    }

    // Create Session
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        SharedConfigState: session.SharedConfigEnable,
    }))

    // Create DynamoDB Client
    client := dynamodb.New(sess, aws.NewConfig())

    // Get Item
    result, err := client.GetItem(&dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("accountsTable"),
        Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            "email": {
                S: aws.String("lhnng@amazon.com"),
            },
        },
    })

    // Catch Error
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("GetItem API call failed:")
        fmt.Println((err.Error()))
    }

    item := Item{}

    // Unmarhsall
    err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &item)

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to unmarshal Record, %v", err))
    }

    // If Item Returns Empty
    if item.Email == "" {
        fmt.Println("Could not find Item")
        return
    }

    // Print Result
    fmt.Println("Found item:")
    fmt.Println("Email:  ", item.Email)

}
```

Comment: Tried this but unfortunately same issue. If email is the primary key, would I have to use Pk / pk or still email would be okay?

Comment: Can you share the output of DescribeTable? If on cli: `aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name 'accountsTable'`

Comment: Is there a way to do that without CLI? Just using console

Comment: If you navigate to your table and take a screenshot of your tables overview and add that to your question it will work.

Comment: Added the table pic

Comment: Thanks, can you share the exact exception being thrown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250868/discussion-between-hbridges-and-lee-hannigan).